# dplyr::mutate unquote RHS

Tags: r, dplyr, nse, rlang

I am wondering how to properly `UQ` string created variable names on the RHS in `dplyr` methods like `mutate`. See the error messages I got in comments in the `wilcox.test` part of this MWE:

```
require(dplyr)

dfMain <- data.frame(
    base = c(rep('A', 5), rep('B', 5)),
    id   = letters[1:10],
    q0   = rnorm(10)
)

backgs <- list(
    A = rnorm(13),
    B = rnorm(11)
)

fun <- function(dfMain, i = 0){

    pcol <- sprintf('p%i', i)
    qcol <- sprintf('q%i', i)

    (
        dfMain %>%
        group_by(id) %>%
        mutate(
            !!pcol := ifelse(
                !is.nan(!!qcol) &
                length(backgs[[base]]),
                wilcox.test(
                    # !!(qcol) - backgs[[base]] 
                    # object 'base' not found
                    # (!!qcol) - backgs[[base]]
                    #  non-numeric argument to binary operator
                    (!!qcol) - backgs[[base]]
                )$p.value,
                NaN
            )
        )
    )

}

dfMain <- dfMain %>% fun()
```

I guess at `!!(qcol) ...` it is interpreted as I would like to unquote the whole expression not only the variable name that's why it does not find `base`? I also found out that `(!!qcol)` returns the string itself so no surprise the `-` operator is unable to handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work as you expect by changing the line where you define `qcol` to:

```r
qcol <- as.symbol(sprintf('q%i', i))
```

That is, since `qcol` was a string, you needed to turn it into a symbol before unquoting for it to be evaluated correctly in your `mutate`. Also I presume the column you wanted to refer to was the `q0` column you defined in your data, not a non-existent column named `qval0`.

Comment: Thanks Mikko! Indeed `q0` I will fix this typo. Also I discovered that `(!!as.name(qcol))` works if I leave `qcol` as a string.