# Best practice for unquoting variable names in the right-hand side of dplyr verbs

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

What is best practice for using variable names as function arguments in the right-hand side of dplyr verbs such as `mutate`?

To apply a function to a variable in a tibble with `mutate` is trivial if we use the column name directly:

```r
mtcars %>%
    select(mpg) %>%
    mutate(mpg = as.character(mpg)) %>%
    glimpse()
# Observations: 32
# Variables: 1
# $ mpg <chr> "21", "21", "22.8", "21.4", "18.7", "18.1", "14.3", "24.4", "22.8", "19.2", "17.8", "16.4", "17.3", "15.2", ...
```

What if we don't know the column name, but it's stored in a variable as a string? As a simple example, let's store the string "mpg" in `var_of_interest`, and then change all the values to "5". This is fine with a simple assignment on the right-hand side of the `mutate` expression (e.g. assigning 5 to all values), if we unquote with `!!` and `:=`:

```r
var_of_interest <- colnames(mtcars)[1]
glimpse(var_of_interest)
# chr "mpg"

mtcars %>% select(var_of_interest) %>%
    mutate(!! var_of_interest := 5) %>%
    glimpse()
# Observations: 32
# Variables: 1
# $ mpg <dbl> 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
```

How should we use `var_of_interest` within a function in the right-hand side of the `mutate` call? For example, inside `as.character`. The following will work, by unquoting `as.name(var_of_interest)`. ([Thanks to this SO post and answer, using as.symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992762/dplyrmutate-unquote-rhs).)

```r
mtcars %>%
    select(var_of_interest) %>%
    mutate(!! var_of_interest := as.character(!! as.name(var_of_interest))) %>%
    glimpse()
# Observations: 32
# Variables: 1
# $ mpg <chr> "21", "21", "22.8", "21.4", "18.7", "18.1", "14.3", "24.4", "22.8", "19.2", "17.8", "16.4", "17.3", "15.2", ...
```

The following, using `rlang::sym`, also works ([thanks to this SO post and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131829/unquote-the-variable-name-on-the-right-side-of-mutate-function-in-dplyr)):

```r
mtcars %>%
    select(var_of_interest) %>%
    mutate(!! var_of_interest := as.character(!! rlang::sym(var_of_interest))) %>%
    glimpse()
# Observations: 32
# Variables: 1
# $ mpg <chr> "21", "21", "22.8", "21.4", "18.7", "18.1", "14.3", "24.4", "22.8", "19.2", "17.8", "16.4", "17.3", "15.2", ...
```

Are there any drawbacks to either of these methods? Should we be using `quo` or `enquo` instead? The latter are discussed in this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) but I'm struggling to understand their usage and I'd love to hear more about this.

Comment: I guess your method works right?  Not sure what is the exact question.  If you are passing a string, use `sym` to convert to symbol and not `quo` the prfefix `en` would be used within a funciton

Comment: Thanks @akrun. Just wondering what the best practice is, I guess `rlang::sym` and `as.name`/`as.symbol` are basically equivalent.

Comment: The `as.symbol` is from `base R`.  it also works, but i would use the functions in `rlang` as it may have some additional checks within the tidyverse env